# How to enable USB debugging on samsung galaxy s7 for React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I have been developing RN project.

Previously, I used `honor phone`, but I have some trouble on this phone.

So I use new `samsung phone`, but when I tried to check devices as follows.

> adb devices

But I couldn't find any real device, I only could find MEMU emulator connected to adb service.

How can I connect my `samsung phone` to adb Service?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to access developer settings on the Galaxy S7

- Launch the settings app from your Home screen or the app drawer.
- Tap on About Device. It's all the way down at the bottom of the menu.
- Tap on Software info.
- Tap on Build number 7 times.

This should allow you to access the developer menu.

Once inside the developer menu, you can enable usb debugging. Make sure you you enable it otherwise it won’t be visible to adb.

It should now appear in `adb devices -l`